# Posting dynamically appended dropdown data

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropddown on my homepage which on select, appends extra dropdowns based on the value selected, as shown in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/harunthuo/he55vwca/3/

The challenge i'm facing is: the dropdowns will be appended dynamically based on the value selected in the 'Children' dropdown. So i'm wondering how i will capture the value(s) of each of the appended dropdowns and capture it in my post. The appended dropdown(s) all have same name and class attribute so if I were to grab the selection of the appended dropdown(s):

```
$('#children-number').on('change', '.children-num', function(e){
    var child_num = e.target.value;
    console.log(child_num);
});
```

This will capture the values selected in each appended dropdown. How do I proceed from here so that i capture these values and send them all to my post so that I capture the value(s) as such:

```
$('#children-number').on('change', '.children-num', function(e){
        var child_num = e.target.value;
        console.log(child_num);

        var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
        data.push({name: 'ages', value: child_num});

        $.post("page.php", data);
});
```

This last part is where i'm a bit stuck. Thanks

Comment: So long as you append the new `select` elements within your `#myForm` then you don't have to amend your code at all. The selected values will be included in the output of `serializeArray()`

Comment: Hey @RoryMcCrossan. When i do this, i'll only get one value. Say i select 2 on the 'Children' dropdown, 2 dropdowns will be appended. if i select values 2 and 4 for the two appended dropdowns and post, my post will only have 4 i.e `["ages"]=> string(1) "4"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, maybe this can help you move along:

try this (but maybe outside the change function, maybe a button-click):

```
 var dataArr = [];  
 $('.children-num').each(function() {
    value = $(this).val();
    dataArr.push(value);
 });
```

and then instead of

```
data.push({name: 'ages', value: child_num});
```

do

```
data.push({name: 'ages', value: dataArr});
```

now you should get

```
["ages"]=> array()
```

or something similar

[here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/he55vwca/8/) which logs the values of the child-nums in the console after you clicked the "click-me" button

Edit: I'd also recommend not doing the `$.post` inside the change event but rather on a button click or similar too, since it would post every time the selection is changed, i don't think that's a good practice

Comment: Brilliant. Was actually in the process of capturing the values in an array but my mistake was i was doing it inside the `change` function. Thankyou for your input